# Trying to work on a paint program

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, drawing, line

I am trying to get this working so only when I click a button on the side does it start drawing using the line tool.

I am new to Javascript/Jquery and I am trying to put these projects together.

http://jsfiddle.net/f7ZZM/99/

```
  <center>
    <div class='example'>
    <p id="colorpickerHolder">
        <canvas id="paint" />
        <br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your html to :

```
<center>
        <div class='example'>
            <p id="colorpickerHolder">
                <canvas id="paint"></canvas>
            </p>
        </div>
</center>
```

Comment: I am looking to get the drawing program to work so when you click a button you draw straight lines and when its not clicked you draw normally. But thank you I have updated the fiddle with the HTML.